# Stripping a HTML file with a specific range in Python

Tags: python

I have a html file Im reading into my python file and in the html file there is a table that includes information in the table the way it's structured is in the code below and my goal is to iterate through that whole html file get the table and if that one of those rows specifically in the description `<td>` tag has the word "vacant" in it I want to be able to get that all that code starting from the opening `<tr>` tag to the closing of it so like if one of the rows has the word vacant in it give me the everything in that inside the `<tr>` tag. So like if inside the whole element has the word "vacant" let me assign that whole element to a variable or append it to a blank html file

I used Beautiful Soup to get rid of all the other code that I dont need essentially all the code from the html file that's not in the table

this is just the structure

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Information</td>
<td>Address</td>
<td>Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Another Row</td>
<td>Another Address</td>
<td>Another Description</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

this code is from the html file

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" width="80%">
<tr><th class="c4"><u>Location of Violation</u></th>
<th class="c5">Date<br/><u>Entered</u></th><th class="c5"><u>Type</u></th>
<th class="c5"><u>Status</u>*</th><th class="c5"><u>Description</u></th>
<th class="c5"><u>Code Enforcement<br/>Activity No.</u></th><th class="c12"><u>Days<br/>Open</u></th></tr>
<tr>
<td class="c6" width="15%">1739 W San Juan Tr</td>
<td class="c6" width="7%">04-02-19</td>
<td class="c6" width="12%">Junk Motor Vehicles</td>
<td class="c6" width="7%">Complian</td>
<td class="c6">Vacant Lot W/Storage, Wop, Refuse, Weeds, Jmvs, Grading</td>
<td class="c6" width="9%"><a href="https://www.tucsonaz.gov/pro/pdsd/permitdetail/T19DV02478" target="_blank">T19DV02478</a></td>
<td class="c3" width="4%"></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="c6" width="15%">1981 W San Juan Tr</td>
    <td class="c6" width="7%">12-24-18</td>
    <td class="c6" width="12%">Refuse</td>
    <td class="c6" width="7%">Complian</td>
    <td class="c6">Since This Company Rented This Vacant Lot It Looks Just Like A             
    Yard From The Hood. We Need More Maintenance In This Yard</td>
    <td class="c6" width="9%"><a 
    href="https://www.tucsonaz.gov/pro/pdsd/permitdetail/T18DV08205" 
    target="_blank">T18DV08205</a></td>
    <td class="c3" width="4%"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="c6" width="15%">1900 W Mistletoe Ci</td>
    <td class="c6" width="7%">05-02-19</td>
    <td class="c6" width="12%">Prop Maint Multiple Types</td>
    <td class="c6" width="7%">Complian</td>
    <td class="c6">Trash And Storage Throughout Property</td>
    <td class="c6" width="9%"><a href="https://www.tucsonaz.gov/pro/pdsd/permitdetail/T19DV03580" target="_blank">T19DV03580</a></td>
    <td class="c3" width="4%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: thank you, and so right now Ive been able to iterate through the html file and then find the table so I have  a variable defined as link and Im using a library called BeautifulSoup so I have a for loop and for link in soup.find_all('table') gives me the html file with just the table so my for loop is                                                                       for link in soup.find_all('table'): and soup is just the variable that has my html file formatted so that I can read the code inside the console

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a nicer solution, but recently I've been using regexes a lot, so:

[Check out documentation on regexes in Python.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) You can write your regex pattern ([I highly recommend this site for designing regexes](https://regex101.com/)), then get all the matches and extract a group.

For you, the regex string would be something like:

`r"<tr.*?>.*?[vV]acant.*?</tr>"`

"r" before the string makes Python take it as a literal string.

".*" is any character (to include newlines, use flag DOTALL), repeated 0 or more times, additional "?" makes it non-greedy (otherwise, it could would've matched first tr opening with last tr closing - you can check it yourself on the second website).

Normally, in a more complex regex, you would need to use groups - but the whole regex is a group in itself.

As for using the regex:

```
for some_variable_name in re.finditer(regex_string_here, your_html_output_here, re.DOTALL)
    some_variable_name.group(0)  # 0th group is the whole regex match
```

Or `re.findall` with the same parameters for a list of matches (already as strings)

Comment: thank you for the help, sorry if this question seems idiotic but could you clarify what the variable regex_string_here is or what is expected of that variable because not really sure what I should be defining as the regex string

Comment: @OmarAl-Bazergan The thing I posted with "For you, the regex string would be something like:" ;P Also, I highly recommend you look into the documentation I linked, regexes are really powerful, although confusing at first.